# Can my app have a custom background in the header?

Tags: app-development

I am working on an app and the logo (by deduction) is 300px x 55px. However it puts that on a grey background.

- Is there a setting somewhere to change the header background?
- If not, is the grey guaranteed to stay the same color (so I can integrate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce describes using different logos for custom apps at http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/dev_tabsetcreate.htm.  Unfortunately, further customizations require [using Visualforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_the_Salesforce_CSS_in_Your_Apps).

Edit:  I have never seen the grey mentioned, but suspect changing that background would upset many customers.  Going on that principle, it is unlikely to be changed without adequate forewarning, if at all.

Answer (score 10):

You can't set a custom background for the header, but you can create your logo as a PNG file and ensure the background of your logo has 100% in the alpha channel, that way it'll sit nicely on the background of the header every time.

In the image software you're using you should be able to add an alpha channel if there isn't one already, then select and erase the area of background you don't want. GIMP has a handy 'Color to Alpha' option in it's Colors menu, though that will result in some slight transparency elsewhere you can fix in the levels dialog.

Here's a particularly nasty logo sporting an alpha channel, you can see how it blends the rainbow section into the white:

[image: A logo with an alpha channel]

This is the exact same image file loaded as a document and set as the logo for an app:

[image: The same logo in Salesforce]

This is how the image appears in GIMP, along with a shot of the alpha channel only, where the black areas are 100% opaque:

[image: The image in GIMP]
[image: The alpha channel]